# PHP display HTML Tags without Echo/Print

Tags: php, html

I've this code:

```
foreach($result as $i->$res)
{
    $link = "Company/" . str_replace(" ", "-", $view->result[$i]->node_title);

    $query = mysql_query("select * from url_alias where alias = '$link'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        $result[$i]->node_title = "<a href = 'http://www.google.com'>asdf</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$i]->node_title = $result[$i]->node_title;
    }           
    $i++;
}
```

How can I dispaly anchor text as link without echo or print it? For now the anchor text just display as a plain text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What framework/cms is this?

Comment: what do u mean by .. without echo  or print.. and why ?? just echo the anchor and till will print as a link..

Comment: @Dainis, i am using drupal and trying to alter views result using hook_view_pre_render.

Comment: @bipen, i can't echo/print it, because i need to add the result into a block in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

if your page is html file

then echo the link like this

```
   <a href = 'http://www.google.com'>asdf</a>
```

if your page is php
then echo the link as you writed.

if your page is html then it will not work the link.